trying to install package, says it's successfully installed, but then not showing up
I have worked with R for a number of years but have never encountered this problem. I recently began a new job and installed rstudio onto my new computer. However, when I go to install packages I need, they never update in the packages list, and say they were never installed? I've tried several solutions already suggested on similar questions but to no avail.
> install.packages("dplyr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘withr’ are not available
also installing the dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘utf8’, ‘cli’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘fansi’ ‘utf8’ ‘cli’ ‘magrittr’ ‘rlang’ ‘tibble’ ‘tidyselect’
  ‘vctrs’ ‘dplyr’
  These will not be installed
installing the source package ‘pillar’

ERROR: dependencies 'cli', 'fansi', 'glue', 'lifecycle', 'rlang', 'utf8', 'vctrs' are not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/myname/OneDrive /Documents/R/R-3.5.0/library/pillar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUjnrSK\downloaded_packages’
> 
> library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’


"WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/" You need to download Rtools

It looks like you are running R 3.5. That's an old version of R. If you update to the latest version, you will likely be able to install packages properly from CRAN.
